# XSLT: Converting text substring to integer value

Tags: xslt-2.0

So I'm working with some lines of XML like this ...

```
<p outputclass="Heading">Cycles 1–5</p>
<p outputclass="Heading">Cycles 6–10</p>
<p outputclass="Heading">Cycles 11–16</p>
```

And what I want to do is pull the numbers out of those, as integer values.

One of the ways I've tried to do this that hasn't worked is ...

```
<xsl:for-each select="p[@outputclass = 'Heading' and starts-with(., 'Cycles ')]">
  <xsl:variable name="cycle_begin_string" select="substring-after(.,'Cycles ') and substring-before(.,'–')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="cycle_end_string" select="substring-after(., '–')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="cycle_begin_number" select="number($cycle_begin_string)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="cycle_end_number" select="number($cycle_end_string)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="cycle_begin_integer" select="xs:integer($cycle_begin_number)"/>
  <xsl:variable name="cycle_end_integer" select="xs:integer($cycle_end_number)"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And yes, I know this could be tidier, but I deliberately broke it into multiple variables in order to troubleshoot where the problem is. Anyway, when I do this, I get an error message of: "Cannot convert double NaN to an integer"

What am I missing here? Because I know that the content being selected is definitely a number. Which I assume means I'm not converting it the right way. But I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: `<xsl:variable name="cycle_begin_string" select="substring-after(.,'Cycles ') and substring-before(.,'–')"/>` looks very odd, the variable name suggests you might want a string but your boolean `and` expression will give you a boolean value. Anyway, which line gives that error?

Comment: Nevertheless I wouldn't expect the error you say you get as the boolean value should be true and the `number` converts it to `1` so all your `cycle_begin_number` and `cycle_begin_integer` should  be`1`. Consider to post minimal but complete samples to allow other to reproduce the problem.

Comment: You're right, of course, thanks. The better way to write that one is ... <xsl:variable name="cycle_begin_string" select="substring-before(substring-after(.,'Cycles '),'–')"/>

And when I did that, it kept the error from happening for that one. But I'm still getting it for this one ... <xsl:variable name="cycle_end_integer" select="xs:integer($cycle_end_number)"/>

I even tried normalize-space for the $cycle_end_string value, thinking maybe some NaN character is getting captured somehow. But still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider to post a minimal but complete example, together with details of which XSLT processor used, to allow others to reproduce the error; based on your question and your comment I have created [the online example running SaxonC HE](https://saxonc-xmlworkbench.azurewebsites.net/?code=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22root%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each%20select%3D%22p%5B%40outputclass%20%3D%20%27Heading%27%20and%20starts-with%28.%2C%20%27Cycles%20%27%29%5D%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22cycle_end_string%22%20select%3D%22substring-after%28.%2C%20%27%E2%80%93%27%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22cycle_end_number%22%20select%3D%22number%28%24cycle_end_string%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22cycle_end_integer%22%20select%3D%22xs%3Ainteger%28%24cycle_end_number%29%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%7B%24cycle_end_integer%7D%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each%3E%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22xml%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0A%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20at%20%7Bcurrent-dateTime%28%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0A%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3Croot%3E%0A%3Cp%20outputclass%3D%22Heading%22%3ECycles%201%E2%80%935%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp%20outputclass%3D%22Heading%22%3ECycles%206%E2%80%9310%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3Cp%20outputclass%3D%22Heading%22%3ECycles%2011%E2%80%9316%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%3C%2Froot%3E%0A&code-type=XSLT&input-type=XML) 12.3 and doing e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="p[@outputclass = 'Heading' and starts-with(., 'Cycles ')]">
      <xsl:variable name="cycle_end_string" select="substring-after(., '–')"/>
      <xsl:variable name="cycle_end_number" select="number($cycle_end_string)"/>
      <xsl:variable name="cycle_end_integer" select="xs:integer($cycle_end_number)"/>
      <div>{$cycle_end_integer}</div>
    </xsl:for-each>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <xsl:comment>Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} at {current-dateTime()}</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

against the input

```
<root>
<p outputclass="Heading">Cycles 1–5</p>
<p outputclass="Heading">Cycles 6–10</p>
<p outputclass="Heading">Cycles 11–16</p>
</root>
```

and it outputs no error but e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div>5</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>16</div>
<!--Run with SAXON HE 12.3 at 2023-11-25T23:08:29.498723Z-->
```

just fine.

Comment: I'll go ahead and accept your answer, because when I isolate this part of the template, it does indeed work for me as well. The problem is that this bit is in the middle of a template (that I didn't write) that's about 500 lines long ... which is part of a 1500+ line XSLT file ... which in turn is the 5th of 6 files that run as a series of "steps". So my best guess is that something outside this section is causing the issue. I was (naively) hoping it was simply a syntax error on my part, or something I didn't understand about how substrings or integers work in XSLT. Anyway, thanks for trying!